# Annihilator is a smooth submanifold of the cotangent bundle

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold and let $Y$ be a smooth submanifold. Denote by $$
TY^0=\{(q,p)\in T^*X\colon q\in Y,p|_{T_qY}=0\}\subseteq T^*X
$$
The annihilator of $Y$. Is is it true that the annihilator is a smooth Lagrangian submanifold of $T^*X?$, and how to see this? The given hint is too use a suitable atlas of charts for $X$ but I don't see how this helps me. Do I have to starts which charts on $X$, restrict them to $Y$ and from there on construct charts for $TY^0$?

Comment: Take a chart in which $Y$ is a linear slice, as usual. As for your last remark, that only works if $Y$ has codimension $1$.

Comment: What do you mean with a linear slice? Could you elaborate on this please

Comment: There are local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ so that $Y$ is given by $x^{k+1}=\cdots=x^n=0$.

Comment: I see what you mean, this is the definition of a smooth submanifold of course. I have been studying Chapter 4 and 5 in Lee, where they construct an atlas for $TX$, but I really don't see how to do something similar now for $TY^0$, could you please elaborate on how to construct charts for $TY^0$?

Comment: Don't worry about charts on the tangent bundle. What are we getting for this subbundle in these coordinates on $X$?

Comment: So for $(q,p)\in TY^0$, we take coordinates $(x^1,..., x^k, v_1,...v_{n-k})$, where the $v_i$ form a basis of the annihilator of the vector space?

Comment: I don't see how I have to deal with the vector space part

Comment: If $Y$ is given by $x^\mu = 0$, $\mu= k+1,\dots,n$, what $1$-forms annihilate its tangent spaces?

Comment: I see those are the cotangent vectors $dx^k,...dx^n$! Thanx for your help!